# Using CGI scripts in Django

Tags: django, cgi

I have a script I'm using to handle form information in the background on my Django server, and it's not giving me any results. Here's part of my views.py file:

```
def run_cgi(request, question_id):
    q = get_object_or_404(Question, pk=question_id)
    return render_to_response('{{ STATIC_URL }}run_cgi.cgi', {'time_overlap': q},context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

From what I gather, {{ STATIC_URL }} references the static folder in the Django directories, where I stored the CGI script. The HTML page is stored in the templates folder, and pointed to using the urls.py file. The HTML consists of two radio buttons (YES/NO), which should be passed to the CGI script. The problem is the CGI script does nothing. Here's the output from the server:

```
[09/Feb/2012 17:41:40] "GET /assert_facts/ HTTP/1.1" 200 689
[09/Feb/2012 17:41:42] "POST /assert_facts/run_cgi.cgi HTTP/1.1" 200 689
```

Answer (score 0):

CGI scripts are not data and should instead be stored in an appropriate directory based on the web server's configuration so that it can execute them properly.

Comment: Turns out the CGI script itself is flawed. Thanks for the information on storing CGI scripts, though.